# RMySQL package for R: installed but not loaded

Tags: mysql, r, centos, rmysql

I am working on R under CentOS 6.7, and I need to gain access to a MySQL database. I successfully downloaded and installed the two packages "DBI" and "RMySQL", but whenever I try to load the library into the R script, I get an error message that RMySQL does not exist.

```
Error in library(RMySQL) : there is no package called ‘RMySQL’
```

I tried the exact same thing on another CentOS 7 server and it didn't work. However, when I try it on my local Windows 7 machine it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Please include the error message you get.

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus I added it to the question